# Uploading files with ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using latest NodeJS and ExpressJS to write a small app. Currently I stuck on uploading a file. :>

routes are configured this way

```
app.get('/Share', share.index);
app.post('/Share/Process', share.processFile);
```

The index view looks like the following

```
form.form-horizontal(action='/Share/Process', method='post')
  legend share a file
  div.control-group
    label.control-label(for='item[actual]') File
    div.controls
      input(type='file', name='item[actual]', required='required')
```

When I follow the ExpressJS API documentation, I should have access to the file, by using **req.files**, which is undefined within the share.processFile method

```
exports.processFile = function(req,res){
  console.log(req.files); // undefined
  console.log(req.body.item.actual); // filename as string
  res.render('share/success', {navigation: { shareClass : 'active'}, downloadKey: 'foo'});
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you're invoking `express.bodyParser` before you define your routes (otherwise `req.files` won't get set)?

Comment: yes bodyParser is invoked w/o any parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the form encoding to `multipart/form-data`, IIRC this should be set for transferring files.